# On what point (hook) does the_/has_post_thumbnail() load?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I got some problems during my loading priority/order that i already discovered. Now i ran into the problem that i can't use any post_thumbnail functions (get_post_thumbnail_id, has_post_thumbnail, the_post_thumbnail): "Call to undefined function"...

Does anyone know at which point these functions are loaded? I would be satisfied if i know after which hook they get loaded.

Thanks!

Edit: I traced down all files that get loaded on my edit custom post type edit screen. It's 64 file from core before my theme files start loading. 
Files starting from #26 are:

- /wp-includes/general-template.php
- /wp-includes/link-template.php
- /wp-includes/author-template.php
- /wp-includes/post.php
- /wp-includes/post-template.php
- /wp-includes/category.php
- /wp-includes/category-template.php
  ... but /wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php doesn't seem to load. Weired ...

Edit 2: post thumbnail support is activated and i can upload images. Only when i try to view them then i get the error about the id function. My problem is that it worked an hour ago and i need to track down whatever is causing this behavior.

Edit 3: Funny. I load my files at init.. right after the file should get included. Plus: I just downloaded wordpress again and replaced the file, so everything from this side should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are included in `wp-settings.php` right after `after_setup_theme` hook and so should be available starting with `init` hook.

Also check if you have [`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) declared in your theme, otherwise these functions won't be included at all.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. You're right. I guess i got some pretty heavy problems. Luckily i'm at v0.7.x and won't release before v1.0 ;)

Comment: I'm such a [insert term here]* !! I rewrote my init routine to include all files from my child themes opt-folder and completely forgot/oversaw that i included them a second time via a function, that adds the theme support on the 'init'-hook during my try to find out why it doesn't work. But without knowing post-thumbnail-template.php won't load... I just deleted the line and now everything works out fine on 'after-theme-setup'-hook. *P.s. No, don't even think about a term ;)